# Non fermarti mai

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm just starting out learning Italian, so I do not know too much about it just yet. Onto the problem... In a few songs I've heard the phrase "non fermarti mai", which supposedly means "do not ever stop [yourself]", directed at singular 'you'. This phrase doesn't make sense to me at all. Should it not be "non ti ferma mai"? Because *ferma* is the singular 'you' imperative and it is reflected at themself (the 'you' person), hence *ti*.

I've also seen the phrase "non ti fermare", which is also weird. Why is there an infinitive of *fermare*?

Could someone explain how these phrases work? Or are these applications of 'artistic license' and thus technically incorrect, but used anyway to make the songs better? If so, what is or are the correct phrase or phrases? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just adding a clarifying article from [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperativo-negativo-prontuario_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No poetic licence, no error. In Italian, in the second singular person, the negative form of the imperative is exactly as you have seen, *non* + infinitive. Compare:
*mangia* / *non mangiare*
*vai* (or *va'*) / *non andare*
*guarda* / *non guardare*

(The plural form is like you'd guess: *mangiate* / *non mangiate* and so on.)

When there is a pronoun, for a reflexive verb as in your example or for other reasons, it can, in general, be either a separate word between *non* and the infinitive or attached to the infinitive (the first construction being the more traditional): *non ti fermare* and *non fermarti* are both correct, as are *non lo mangiare* and *non mangiarlo*, and so on.
In the affirmative form, modern Italian only admits the forms with the enclitic pronouns at the end (*fermati*, *mangialo*), while *ti ferma*, *lo mangia* is currently wrong (while actually an old form you could find in some opera libretto).

Comment: Aah, I see! So, if there was no negation, then indeed one would use *ferma* as the 2nd singular person imperative: "Ti ferma!" to tell someone directly to stop? Or would this become something like "Fermati!"? What if I tell them "Stop it!"; would that be "Lo ferma!"? Would the contraction be "Fermalo!"?

Comment: You're right, I didn't cover this. Let me add it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! It all makes sense to me now! It'd upvote your answer, but it won't let me due to insufficient reputation...

Comment: «Stop it!» --> «Smettila!» or, using the **interrogative form**, «La smetti?»

Comment: @randomatlabuser Why is it "Smettila!" rather than "Smettilo!"? I thought refering to *it* would be *lo*, just like "lo so" means "I know it". I'm unfamiliar with *smettere* though; is there a reason why you used this instead of *fermare*?

Comment: @Joffysloffy That is a very good question indeed! As reported in [Treccani's article](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/la2/), "la" is sometimes used to indicate a generic situation (which is feminine). «La smetti con questa cosa? Smettila! Finiscila! Piantala!».

Comment: @randomatlabuser I see. My Italian isn't adequate to understand the article. I'll ask it therefore: does this mean that one can always use *lo*, but if one wants to be more specific and one knows the object or person, to which or whom one is referring, is feminine, then one may choose to use *la* instead? To sum up: is *lo* always correct and is *la* optional?

Comment: You use "la" when it is clear that you are referring to something that is feminine, "situazione", "cosa", "vicenda", "realtà", etc.

Comment: @randomatlabuser: Actually, I would not be able to point out what exactly is referred to by “la” in such expression as “finiscila” and the like. I'd simply say that they are idioms meaning “No more of it!” or whatever. “Finiscilo”, on the other hand, needs a clear object (e.g., “il piatto di pasta”) and is not an idiom but an “actual” sentence.

Comment: @DaG The point is that originally these **were** actual sentences, they got shortened and with time people just forgot what they originally referred to. «Come la va [la vita, la cosa, la vicenda, etc.]?», «Eh, la va male!», «E adesso come la mettiamo [la cosa]?», «Chi la fa [la canagliata, la cosaccia, etc.], l'aspetti!» (the examples are from [Treccani's article](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/la2/)).

Comment: @randomatlabuser: You are right, of course. I was only pointing out that in contemporary use you don't need to look or to postulate a specific object, but only to know that those verbs are used like that.

Answer (score 4):

"Non fermarti mai" is technically **"Never Stop"**

"Non ti fermare" is **"Don't Stop"**

"Non ti ferma mai" is "He/she/it never stops you".

The song author probably is just saying that you should never stop doing something, not that someone should never stop you.

Fermare, as you said, is indeed the infinitive of fermare (to stop).

Comment: I don't quite see why though. Wouldn't you use the imperative for that, not the infinitive? That seems really odd. Moreover, what kind of conjugation is *fermarti*; I cannot find it anywhere? I know that "non ti ferma mai" means "It/He never stops you", because *ferma* is the 3rd person singular indicative form of *fermare*, but it is also the 2nd person singular imperative form of *fermare*, so why is that not used in these cases, since the song makes it clear that it is the intention of the author to say that. Thanks!

Comment: Fermarti is "fermare te". It is a negative reflexive form. It is build with an infinitive and a personal pronoun.
The positive reflexive form is built with imperativee + personal pronoun: Fermati

Comment: Ooh, I see! Thank you. Does this mean that one would solely use the 2nd singular person imperative *ferma* if it is used non-reflexively and non-negatively?

Comment: @Joffysloffy correct, if you mean to say that the person you are addressing to is mean to stop something or somebody