# What mood is "Non ti arrabbiare!"?

Tags: verbs, moods

Is this "imperativo" or "riflessivo"?
I am confused as it has the reflexive pronoun.

I had a look on books and net but cannot find a definite answer.

Ciao e grazie!

Comment: What mood is “don’t get angry”?

Comment: I don't think "riflessivo" is really a mood. You can have a reflexive verb conjugated in different moods.

Comment: See also https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/non-fermarti-mai and especially https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7796/what-mood-is-non-avere-paura.

Comment: To be precise, *arrabbiarsi* is not a *verbo riflessivo*. It is something called *verbo intransitivo pronominale* (see [here](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-pronominali_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/)), the difference being that while actual reflexive verbs denote actions that you happen to do to yourself (for instance, *lavarsi* as opposed to *lavare un'altra persona*) the intransitivi pronominali describe actions/states of mind, as *arrabbiarsi*, *innamorarsi*..., that aren't actually reflexive: you don't actually “arrabbiare” yourself (nor you can “arrabbiare” someone else).

Comment: As others have said *riflessivo* is not a mood, but rather a *voice* (the Italian version of the Indoeuropean mediopassive voice)

Answer (score 8):

The verb is “arrabbiarsi”, in reflexive form. The mood is imperative. When the imperative (second person singular) is used in a negative sentence, the infinitive must replace the normal inflected form: *non fare agli altri…* versus *fa’ agli altri…*.